# toggleclass is not being refreshed even If i try to refresh it

Tags: javascript, jquery

the classes are not being added !

```
jQuery('.menu-toggle').on('click', function(){

    jQuery('body, #mobile-menu ul').toggleClass('menu-open');
    jQuery('#wrapper').toggleClass('has-menu');


});
```

already tried using refresh .

Comment: Where's your HTML?Please post a plunkr or fiddle.

Comment: `jQuery('body, #mobile-menu ul')` why do you have `,`?

Comment: What do u want to achieve ?

Comment: Please check this one jQuery('body, #mobile-menu ul')... There is syntactical error here

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Has jQuery been decalred before this script runs?